# Using Format as cost in SQL remove decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently using a Format as 'C' in my SQL Query but they would like me to remove the decimal places and round up. How can I change the below to remove decimals?

,format(ISNULL(piv.Monday,0),'C') as [Mon]

Answer (score 0):

How about just using `round()`?

```
round(piv.monday, 0) as Mon
```

Or using `round()` and converting to a number:

```
convert(numeric(38, 0), round(piv.monday, 0)) as Mon
```

Or as a string with commas:

```
format(round(piv.monday, 0), 'N0') as Mon
```

Comment: I tried using a round before hand and I am getting the below error:

Comment: Well I'm not getting an error now but it's still giving me the decimals. I think it's because I am formatting as cost but they need me to do that without the cents.